# Bind KendoUI grid with Model data in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

For example, I have a view with model `IEnumerable<Correspondence>`. I want to bind it to KendoUI grid. What should I do? I've tried

```
    @model IEnumerable<Correspondence>
    <div id="Correspondence"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Correspondence').kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                        data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
                        editable: { destroy: true },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 15,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "Id",
                                fields: {
                                    Subject: { type: "string" },
                                    CorrespondenceType: { type: "number" },
                                    SentDate: { type: "date" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    navigatable: true,
                    selectable: "row",
                    filterable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: true
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            title: "Subject",
                            field: "Subject"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Type",
                            field: "CorrespondenceType"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Sent Date",
                            field: "SentDate",
                            format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                        },
                        {
                            command: [{ name: "openCorrespondence", text: "Open", className: "k-grid-openLaboratory", imageClass: "k-icon k-i-maximize", click: Open },
                                { name: "deleteCorrespondence", text: "Delete", className: "k-grid-deleteLaboratory", imageClass: "k-icon k-delete", click: Delete },
                                { name: "EditCorrespondence", text: "Edit", className: "k-grid-editLaboratory", imageClass: "k-icon k-edit", click: Edit }],
                            title: "Action"
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }); // end ready
    </script>
```

But it doesn't work. The table even doesn't show up. Please help me. Thank you.

**Edited!!!**

Comment: Because this is not my project, so I have to follow them. Yes, I'll try :)

Comment: Really? OK, I'll try to look at my code more carefully, maybe I'll figure out why. Thank you so much.

Comment: My `Correspondence` model has more than 3 properties above, but I only want to display that 3 things, does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. Because I used command column, so I have to add 3 functions: `Open`, `Edit`, and `Delete`. Then, the grid showed successfully.